# Can I build an image classifier with only one class (i.e watermelon)

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, image-classification

I'm new to this so I don't really know what to do.

I have this dataset of watermelon and I want to create an image classifier that tells whether the input image is watermelon or not based on the features of the dataset.

I tried doing ORB where I loop through all the images in the dataset and try to get the descriptors of each image and append them to the list.

```
imagePaths = list(paths.list_images('...'))

orb = cv.ORB_create(nfeatures=1000)

keyPoints = []
descriptors = []

for imagePath in imagePaths:
    image = cv.imread(imagePath, 0)
    key_points, descriptor = orb.detectAndCompute(image, None)
    keyPoints.append(key_points)
    descriptors.append(descriptor)
```

Then I read the input image and also get the descriptor using ORB.

```
test = cv.imread('apple_158989157.jpg', 0)
keypoint_test, desc_test = orb.detectAndCompute(test, None)
```

After I get the descriptors I use BFMatcher to match the descriptors between the dataset and the input image. Looping through the descriptors stored in the list and matching it with the descriptor of the input image

```
bf = cv.BFMatcher()
for descriptor in descriptors:
        matches = bf.knnMatch(desc_test , descriptor, k = 2)

        for m, n in matches:
            if m.distance < 0.75 * n.distance:
                goodMatches.append([m])
```

In order to know if it is watermelon or not I declare a threshold.

```
threshold = 1500
if len(goodMatches) > threshold:
        print('Watermelon found!')
    else:
        print('No watermelon found!')
```

I tried using these on 18 different fruits and 10 watermelons, 18 out of 18, it classifies it as Not watermelon, and 2 out of 10 watermelons were classified as Not Watermelon.

However, is there any method or a better way to have an image classifier with one class only?

PS. I have 120 images of watermelon as dataset.

Comment: Have you had a look at autoencoders? Conceptually simple to implement with libraries like keras they would very quickly allow you to classify singular types of images from all types of images. Also could you include the approximate size on your dataset? If you had only 10 watermelons to train features on its probably not going to be very robust.

Comment: Oh sorry, I have edited and included the number of watermelons I used as a dataset.

Comment: Do not really see any implementation issues with your approach but typical steps to improve your performance -> Generate more data via data augmentation,data normalization, tune your threshold with a reasonable performance threshold to stop(i,e, set a performance goal). Your test dataset already sets your algorithm at 87% accuracy. Once again would highly recommend an autoencoder approach. A quick search will list many tutorials for it which you can follow quite easily.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll take into account the steps to improve the performance of my code and will look into what are autoencoders since it's my first time encountering it.